# getting id from url

Tags: php, laravel-5

how can i get the id passed with the url and save it in an input ? and the controller is like that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use URL;
use DB;

class productController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getIndex(){
        $in=URL::get('id');
        $product=DB::table('products')->get(['id','name','salary','sale','p_salary','n_salary','best','type','image_name','category_id','sub_id','incategory_id','new']);
        return view('contents.products')->with('product',$product)
                                        ->with('in',$in);

    }
}
```

and the view is like that :

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<form method="POST" action="{{action('productController@getIndex')}}" enctype="multipart/form-code">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<div class="em-wrapper-main">
    <div class="container container-main">
        <div class="em-inner-main">
            <div class="em-wrapper-area02"></div>
            <div class="em-wrapper-area03"></div>
            <div class="em-wrapper-area04"></div>
            <div class="em-main-container em-col1-layout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="em-col-main col-sm-24">
                        <div class="page-title category-title">
                            <h1>Shoes</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="category-products">
                            <div class="toolbar-top">
                                <div class="toolbar">
                                    <div class="pager">
                                        <p class="amount"> Items 1 to 12 of 20 total</p>
                                        <div class="pages">
                                            <ol>
                                                <li class="current">1</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">2</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="next i-next" href="#" title="Next"> <img src="{{asset('assets/images/pager_arrow_right.gif')}}" alt="Next" class="v-middle" /> </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.pager -->
                                    <div class="sorter">
                                        <p class="view-mode">
                                            <label>View as:</label> <strong title="Grid" class="grid">Grid</strong> <a href="category-one-column-list.html" title="List" class="list">List</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="sort-by toolbar-switch">
                                            <div class="toolbar-title">
                                                <label>Sort By</label>
                                                <select class="sortby" name="sortby">
                                                    <option value="position" selected="selected"> Position</option>
                                                    <option value="name"> Name</option>
                                                    <option value="price"> Price</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="#" title="Set Descending Direction"><img src="{{asset('assets/images/i_asc_arrow.png')}}" alt="Set Descending Direction" class="v-middle" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="limiter toolbar-switch">
                                            <div class="toolbar-title">
                                                <label>Show</label>
                                                <select class="toolbar-show">
                                                    <option value="12" selected="selected"> 12</option>
                                                    <option value="24"> 24</option>
                                                    <option value="36"> 36</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.sorter -->
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.toolbar-top -->
                            <div id="em-grid-mode">
                                <ul class="emcatalog-grid-mode products-grid emcatalog-disable-hover-below-mobile">
                                    @foreach($product as $p)
                                    @foreach($in as $n)
                                    @if($p->incategory_id == $n->id)
                                    <li class="item first">
                                        <div class="product-item">
                                            <div class="product-shop-top">
                                                <a href="{{action('productdetailController@getProduct' , array('id' => $p->id))}}" title="{{$p->name}}" class="product-image"> 
                                                <img class="em-img-lazy img-responsive em-alt-hover" src="{{asset('images/')}}/{{$p->image_name}}" width="220" height="220" alt="WIASSI Version 1" /> 
                                                <img id="product-collection-image-206" class="em-img-lazy img-responsive em-alt-org" src="{{asset('images/')}}/{{$p->image_name}}" width="220" height="220" alt="WIASSI Version 1" />
                                                <span class="bkg-hover"></span> </a>
                                                <div class="bottom">
                                                    <div class="em-btn-addto text-center ">
                                                        <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="206"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                                                            <li><button type="submit" class="link-wishlist" name="submit" title="Add to Wishlist">Add to Wishlist</button> 
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li><a href="#206" class="link-compare" title="Add to Compare">Add to Compare</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="quickshop-link-container"> <a href="#" class="quickshop-link" title="Quickshop">Quickshop</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product-shop">
                                                <div class="f-fix">
                                                    <h2 class="product-name text-center  "><a href="product_detail" title="{{$p->name}}"> {{$p->name}} </a></h2>
                                                    <div class=" text-center">
                                                        <div class="ratings">
                                                            <div class="rating-box">
                                                                <div class="rating" style="width:%"></div>
                                                            </div> <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="206">(0)</a></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="text-center ">
                                                        <div class="price-box"> <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-206"> <span class="price"  content="{{$p->salary}}">${{$p->salary}}</span> </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="desc std text-center em-element-display-hover">{{$p->name}}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.product-item -->
                                    </li>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /.em-grid-mode -->

                            <div class="toolbar-bottom em-box-03">
                                <div class="toolbar">
                                    <div class="pager">
                                        <p class="amount"> Items 1 to 12 of 20 total</p>
                                        <div class="pages">
                                            <ol>
                                                <li class="current">1</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">2</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="next i-next" href="#" title="Next"> 
                                                    <img src="{{asset('assets/images/pager_arrow_right.gif')}}" alt="Next" class="v-middle" /> </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.pager -->
                                    <div class="sorter">
                                        <p class="view-mode">
                                            <label>View as:</label> <strong title="Grid" class="grid">Grid</strong> <a href="category-one-column-list.html" title="List" class="list">List</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="sort-by toolbar-switch">
                                            <div class="toolbar-title">
                                                <label>Sort By</label>
                                                <select class="sortby" name="sortby">
                                                    <option value="position" selected="selected"> Position</option>
                                                    <option value="name"> Name</option>
                                                    <option value="price"> Price</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="#" title="Set Descending Direction"><img src="{{asset('assets/images/i_asc_arrow.png')}}" alt="Set Descending Direction" class="v-middle" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="limiter toolbar-switch">
                                            <div class="toolbar-title">
                                                <label>Show</label>
                                                <select class="toolbar-show">
                                                    <option value="12" selected="selected"> 12</option>
                                                    <option value="24"> 24</option>
                                                    <option value="36"> 36</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.sorter -->
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.toolbar-bottom -->
                        </div><!-- /.category-products -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.em-main-container -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.em-wrapper-main -->
</form>
@stop
```

how to get the products that have the incategory_id passed with the url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Request` facade to get the `id` and then, use the `where` method to get the requested `product` like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Request;
use DB;

class productController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        $in=Request::get('id');
        $product=DB::table('products')->where('incategory_id', $in)->get(['id','name','salary','sale','p_salary','n_salary','best','type','image_name','category_id','sub_id','incategory_id','new']);
        return view('contents.products')->with('product',$product);
    }
}
```

Also, you could `type-hint` the `Illuminate\Http\Request`:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    $in=$request->get('id');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: u say it should be written like that : $in=Request::get('id'); ?? then how can i deal with it in the form !!!!

Comment: it gives me that error : Non-static method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::get() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: You could import the facade. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: wait wait the above is right but why is it invalid argument for foreach ?

Comment: won't i change anything in the form ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to remove the `foreach` because I pass only the requested product to the `view` :)

Comment: but if i removed the foreach, that will be wrong her :  @if($p->incategory_id == $n->id)

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that. I updated my answer. Also you need to remove this `if` and the nested `foreach`.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry for the confusion, I missed the last line of your question :)